# if/else statement covering days of the week with times

Tags: php

I am new to php and trying to solve a simple if/else statement.  I have created two different tables to display on a website.  I would like table 1 to display between Sunday at 2:00pm and Thursday at 8:00pm.  I would like table 2 to display the rest of the time.  How do I make that happen?

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ($current_time > strtotime('sunday this week 2:00pm') && $current_time <    
  strtotime('thursday this week 8:00pm')){?>

echo table 1
<?php

 }else{?>   
echo table 2
<?php


   }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This week started on Monday. Therefore, if it's before Thursday 8 pm, it cannot be after Sunday 2pm.

Comment: You do realize that Americans, for example, start their weeks on Sunday..?

Comment: I do, but [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) says in the Changelog that it's Monday through Sunday.

Comment: Well in that case, I never said anything. ;)